# How do I line up a label and a inputCheckbox in a row?

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I have:

```
  <label for="request-true">True</label>
  <apex:inputCheckbox id="request-true"/>
```

Result:[image]

Desired Result: True [ ]

Answer (score 2):

To line up a `label` and a `inputCheckbox` in a row. There can be many solution to do this alignment. I am sharing the one way of doing this:

**Code:**

```
<apex:page >
<apex:form >
  <table>
  <td style="padding: 4px ! important;"><label for="request-true">True</label></td>
  <td><apex:inputCheckbox id="request-true"/></td>
  </table>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I copy paste your code into my VF page and it seem aligned.Check out the pic below.

[image]

I suspect ,your code contain CSS that control the style.You may want to check it using Inspect Element in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

If you are inside an `apex:pageBlockSection` and want the standard styling:

```
<apex:pageBlockSection>
    ...
    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        <apex:outputLabel for="request-true" value="True"/>
        <apex:inputCheckbox id="request-true"/>
   </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
   ....
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because Visualforce uses typical HTML, you could even include [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) to not only align labels and fields, but also make your pages suitable for mobile.

Once you've included it via either a static resource or linked to a CDN, you can reference some of Bootstrap's classes with your forms. There's a few, different ways of doing this. Here's an example though:

```
<apex:form>
  <div class="form-control>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <label for="request-true">True</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <apex:inputCheckbox id="request-true"/>
      </div>
  </div>
</apex:form>
```

Although there's different (and better) examples than the one I've provided here. But that would work and be responsive in mobile.

The only piece of advice I'd give you is to try to avoid using tables where possible.