# Alignments and Labels are getting missed in the apex:pageblock in VF page

Tags: apex, visualforce, pageblocksection, panelgrid, pageblocksectionitem

I have a VF Page and the labels for the input checkbox are getting missed. The below is the VF page:

```
<apex:pageBlock title="Generate Schedule of Investments Report for {! fund.Name}">
   <apex:pageBlockSection id="fields">
      <apex:inputField label="Report as of" value="{! dateContainer.As_Of_Date__c}" required="true" />
      <apex:outputText />
   </apex:pageBlockSection>
   <!--<BR></BR>-->
   <apex:actionRegion >
      <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">
         <apex:inputCheckBox label="Show Unrealized Rounds" value="{!includeUnrealizedRounds}" selected="true"  />
         <apex:inputCheckBox label="Show Realized Rounds" value="{!includeRealizedRounds}" selected="false"  />
      </apex:pageBlockSection>
      <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">
         <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
            <apex:panelGrid columns="1">
               <apex:outputText >
                  <b> Unrealized Gain/(Loss) Fields: </b>
               </apex:outputText>
               <apex:inputCheckBox label="#shares" value="{!includeShares}" disabled="{!disableCheckboxOfShares}" selected="true" />
               <apex:inputCheckBox label="Cost/Share" value="{!includeCostPerShare}" selected="true">
                  <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!disableCheckBoxes}" rerender="fields1"></apex:actionSupport>
               </apex:inputCheckBox>
               <!--<BR></BR>-->
               <apex:inputCheckBox label="FMV/Share" value="{!includeFmvPerShare}" selected="true">
                  <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!disableCheckBoxes}" rerender="fields1"></apex:actionSupport>
               </apex:inputCheckBox>
            </apex:panelGrid>
         </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
         <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
            <apex:panelGrid columns="1">
               <apex:outputText >
                  <b>Realized Gain/(Loss) Fields:</b>
               </apex:outputText>
               <!--<BR></BR>-->
               <apex:inputCheckBox label="Amount Invested" value="{!includeAmountInvested}" disabled="{!disableCheckboxForAmountInvested}"
                  />
               <!--<BR></BR>-->
               <apex:inputCheckBox label="Proceeds" value="{!includeProceeds}" disabled="{!disableCheckboxForProceeds}" />
               <!--<BR></BR>-->
               <apex:inputCheckBox label="Escrow Shares" value="{!includeEscrowShares}" />
            </apex:panelGrid>
         </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
      </apex:pageBlockSection>
   </apex:actionRegion>
   <apex:pageBlockSection title="Preview" columns="1" collapsible="true" rendered="{! pdfReference != null}">
      <embed src="{! pdfReference}" type="application/pdf" width="85%" height="700" />
   </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Below is the image where the labels are getting missed while the checkboxes are displayed.

[image]

My guess is that:

1. After adding the `<apex:actionRegion>` the labels are getting missed.

Expected output:
I want the labels to get displayed along with the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Potential Solution i found is to wrap your every checkbox in `<apex:pageBlockSectionItem></apex:pageBlockSectionItem>` tag and inside of it use `<apex:outputLabel />` to show labels for each of the checkbox.

Note:-
you need to do this for every checboxInput

For Example:-

```html
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    <apex:inputCheckBox  selected="true" id="Cost-Shareid">
        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange"  rerender="fields1"></apex:actionSupport>
    </apex:inputCheckBox>
    <apex:outputLabel for="Cost-Shareid" value="Cost/Share"/>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

There are some similar threads that you refer.

[here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/151150/inputcheckbox-label-is-not-displaying)

[here also](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/98263/how-do-i-line-up-a-label-and-a-inputcheckbox-in-a-row)